# How to prevent wordpress site detection from tools like Wappalyzer or similar tools

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to prevent wordpress site detection from tools like Wappalyzer or similar tools. i tried "Hide my Wp" plugin and others, but nothing is working for me. wappalyzer browser add on still show the wordpress icon. I see the wappalyzer script how they detect the wordpress (https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json)

They use this code to detect:

```
"WordPress": {
            "cats": [
                1,
                11
            ],
            "env": "^wp_username$",
            "html": [
                "<link rel=[\"']stylesheet[\"'] [^>]+wp-(?:content|includes)",
                "<link[^>]+s\\d+\\.wp\\.com"
            ],
            "icon": "WordPress.png",
            "implies": "PHP",
            "meta": {
                "generatenter code hereor": "WordPress( [\\d.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
            },
            "script": "/wp-includes/",
            "website": "wordpress.org"
        }
```

Please tell me anyone how do i stop to detection my website. If anyone have any idea or solve this type of issue?? please give me the newest resource link or way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wappalyzer looks at the html code and detects wp-content/ or wp-includes/
what you can try is to rewrite every url using htaccess so that it points to another source.

what my friends use is this plugin: Hide My WP ( I don't know the owner or creator of this plugin ).

Comment: i changed that 3 folder name and also removed wordperss auto generate meta tag but not works.. you can check this url and check the view page source [ http://valodam.com/sync ]

Comment: I can still see wp-content in your html source

Comment: i changed it for that reason you see this nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent WordPress site detection from tools like Wappalyzer or similar tools by using [Hide My WP Ghost](https://hidemywpghost.com/) is hiding your website from Wappalyzer.  Hide My WordPress Ghost is the latest product designed to ensure perfect protection against hackers around the world.

Reference article: [Click here](https://hidemywpghost.com/hide-wordpress-from-wappalyzer/#:%7E:text=To%20set%20the%20Ghost%20Mode,type%20and%20you%27re%20done.)!