# How to isolate part of a link in BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

As a starter project I'm using BS4 to identify sites that use WordPress.

I'm having trouble getting the identifier right. I know that WordPress sites have **/wp-content/** links in the html. But I'm not isolating them correctly.

Here are some link examples:

```
img src="https://variety.com/wp-content/...
href="https://variety.com/wp-content/...
```

I've been playing with lots of variations on:

```
find_wordpress = soup.find('a', href = "wp-content")
```

But I'm not getting it right. The domain will change so I just need to isolate the /wp-content/ part.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: you would have to use `regex` or function which uses `"wp-content" in href`

Comment: if you need all links then use `find_all`

Comment: if you want to only identify `WordPress` then maybe you should use `if "wp-content" in html` without using `BS4`

Comment: Hi @furas That's an interesting idea! I though BS4 was needed to open and look through the html. Is there another way?

Comment: `html` is a string and you can use string functons or regex - but if you need something more complex then `BS4` or `lxml` is more useful. Sometime `BS4` can be even more useful because it can use regex or functions to filter items.

Comment: There is browser extension [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) to recognize tools/CMS used by web page - and I found question [How to prevent wordpress site detection from tools like Wappalyzer or similar tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015158/how-to-prevent-wordpress-site-detection-from-tools-like-wappalyzer-or-similar-to/) which shows what rules it uses to detect WordPress.

Comment: Oh wow, that's awesome. Though I'm not sure why anyone would want to bother hiding the fact their site is built using WP. Thanks!

Comment: If I write:  if "wp-content" in html:" I get the error that html isn't defined (even with BS4). Does the requests module know the term 'html'? How would I define html if it's just running through a series of urls?

Comment: `html` has to be string with HTML and it has nothing to do with `BS` and `soup` - you get it directly from `requests` - ie. `html = requests.get(...).text` and it is the same string which you use in `soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(...).text, 'lxml')`

Comment: Thanks @furas you've really given me a lot to work on and practice. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only what to identify `WordPress` then maybe you could use

```
"/wp-content/" in html
```

but sometimes it can be misleading if `/wp-content/` is used in some other text.

---

```
html = '''<a href="http://one.com/wp-content/1"></a>'''

result = ('/wp-content/' in html1)
print('result 1:', result)

html = '''<a href="http://one.com/2"></a>'''

result = ('/wp-content/' in html)
print('result 2:', result)
```

---

If you need to check `href` then you can use `regex`

```
soup.find('a', href=re.compile(r'.*/wp-content/.*'))
```

or even

```
soup.find('a', href=re.compile(r'/wp-content/'))
```

Or you can use function

```
def test_link(link):
    return '/wp-content/' in link

result = soup.find('a', href=test_link)
```

or the same with `lambda`

```
soup.find('a', href=lambda link:'/wp-content/' in link)
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1 = '''<a href="http://one.com/wp-content/1"></a>'''
html2 = '''<a href="http://one.com/2"></a>'''

result = ('/wp-content/' in html1)
print('1:', result)

result = ('/wp-content/' in html2)
print('2:', result)


soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'lxml')

import re

result = soup1.find('a', href=re.compile(r'/wp-content/'))
print('1:', result, '-->', (result is not None))
result = soup2.find('a', href=re.compile(r'/wp-content/'))
print('2:', result, '-->', (result is not None))

#def test(link):
#    return '/wp-content/' in link

result = soup1.find('a', href=lambda link:'/wp-content/' in link)
print('1:', result, '-->', (result is not None))
result = soup2.find('a', href=lambda link:'/wp-content/' in link) 
print('2:', result, '-->', (result is not None))
```